# Covariance matrix of an adaptive filter input

Tags: adaptive-filters, covariance

I run many times in equations containing the trace of covariance matrix of an adaptive filter input. But it is not really clear what it is.

For example in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=902113) the input covariance matrix is

$$\textbf{R} = E\left(\textbf{u}_i^*\textbf{u}_i \right)$$

where:

- $\textbf{u}_i$ is row vector of input (seems to be regression vector in given time)
- $^*$ denotes Hermitian conjugation (complex conjugation for scalars)
- $E$ is not explained, but I would expect it is the expected value

Questions:

1. What does it mean?
2. How does the matrix look like, what is the shape of it?
3. How do I estimate it from input data $\textbf{U}$ - matrix where one row represents one input vector?

Comment: wikipedia has an article on covariance matrices. I really don't understand the question – from the formula alone, it's clear that its *shape* is quadratic, and honestly: I think you can come up with a way of estimating an expectation value from multiple observations.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for reply. If I understand you correctly, then in case of fllter size 10 and data of size 1000 input vectors, I should create 1000 matrices (of size 10x10) and estimate mean value of them (10x10 result)?

Comment: sounds like a good estimator :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller If this is correct answer, then please make an proper answer so I can accept it. I do not think that I am the only one who do not find this solution obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Covariance Matrix is commonly defined as

$$\mathbf Q = E\left[ (\mathbf x -\mathbf\mu_{x})(\mathbf x -\mathbf\mu_{x})^*\right]$$
with $\mu$ denoting the mean value, i.e. $\mu_{x}=E\left[\mathbf x\right]$, and $\mathbf x$ being column vectors. The fact that you define the covariance matrix as

$$\mathbf{R}_i = E\left[\textbf{u}_i^*\textbf{u}_i \right]$$

indicates that your $\mathbf u_i$ have zero mean and are row vectors; that might be a result of the signal model you use, but it's pretty non-standard.

Furthermore, the product of a column vector with its hermitian is inherently hermitian (symmetric if real).

Now, one way to estimate an expectation value from multiple observations. Wikipedia [has an article on estimating covariance matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices), so here's just the gist: the most intuitive estimator is the *sample covariance matrix*; adapted to your formula, that'd be

$$\hat{\mathbf R} = \frac1{N-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \mathbf u_i^*\mathbf u_i$$

Comment: I think if you know that the mean value is zero, then the proper formula is $\hat{\mathbf{R}} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{u}_i^* \mathbf{u}_i$. The division by $N-1$ comes about when you need to estimate the mean value from the data as well.

Answer (score 0):

In adaptive filtering it is auto-correlation matrix.  E is expectation operator.
It is a square matrix and complex conjugate symmetric. It measures the signal auto-correlation.
The u vector is an input vector, also called reference vector.